# Visiting Kathmandu, stay in Themel or Nagarkot?

Tags: nepal, kathmandu

I am visiting Kathmandu in October and wondering if I should stay in Themel or Nagarkot.

- Themel is more touristy and has more hotels.
- Nagarkot is a bit far, but is more unspoiled.

I would prefer to stay in Nagarkot, but need to know how much extra time/driving I will need to stay in Nagarkot.

Comment: It seems you're providing an answer but no question. Usually, you would describe your preferences and people would tell you what's touristy and what's unspoiled ;-)

Comment: @Relaxed: I would prefer to stay at Nagarkot, but I want to know how much extra driving time I am looking at compared to staying in Themel.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to reflect that because at the moment it's really unclear (to me at least) that this was what you were after.

Answer (score 2):

Nagarkot sits up in the hills surrounding Kathmandu, about 25 kilometers away.  You would be looking at an hour to an hour & a half on average to downtown Kathmandu (maybe more during peak traffic times).

Answer (score 0):

An hour's drive from downtown-Kathmandu to Nagarkot is worth the time. Nagarkot provides picturesque views of sunrise and sunset (in a good weather condition); scenery of the unblocked Himalayan range and panoramic views along the way. I definitely would have taken [Nagarkot tour](http://basecampadventure.com/nepal/kathmandu-nagarkot-tour/).[image] And by the way, it's Thamel; not Themel. No offense.

Comment: ARe you linked in some way to "BaseCameAdventure"?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about the time taken to reach Nagarkot.